# Prove that any interval $(a,b)$ with an algebraic operation "*" forms group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can one prove that on any given set $(a,b)\ ,\ a,b\in R$, there exists an algebraic operation $"*"$ that, together with the given interval, form a group? We know that $(a,b)$ is has an upper and lower bound.

Comment: Any open interval is equinumerous to $\Bbb R$, and the real numbers have a natural group operation, to wit $(\Bbb R,+)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a bijective function $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ (a translated and scaled $\tan$ should do the work). Then define
$$t*s:=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))$$

Comment: where $s,t \in (a,b)$, I suppose

Answer (score 1):

Hint: any open interval $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under addition, use the homeomorphism to produce the group operation on $(a,b).$